# Page Icon Connected to Welcome Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, wiki

This is a very simple question, but not 100% sure.
Scenario: I would like to change the URL of the icon for a sub-site without using code.

During research and testing there are many ways by changing the master page by change and adding code.  But isn't there a way to do so without script by changing the welcome page URL for the sub-site? Will this cause issues with the parent icon URL. I don't want that to change just the sub-site URL.

Update from original: 
I am trying to change the URL for the icon image that appears in the upper right hand corner of the page. By default it points to the sub-site home page. If want to create a new home page, the icon is staying the old URL. I want to make sure icon URL will match the new home page not point back to the old home page. Thanks James for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trying to change the URL to point to another page but keep the same logo. You can go to the URL page you want and select and in the page ribbon select Make Homepage from the Page Actions.

[image: Make Homepage Link]

This will change the URL the logo leads to for your subsite.

Comment: I am trying to change the URL for the icon image that appears in the upper right hand corner of the page.  By default it points to the sub-site home page.  If want to create a new home page, the icon is staying the old URL.  I want to make sure icon URL will match the new home page not point back to the old home page.  Thanks James for your help.  I should of included more detail in my original question.  I am updating the question now.

Answer (score 1):

To change the icon URL for a subsite, change the Logo URL property in the subsite's > site settings > Title, Description and Icon page. Just remember that the users of the subsite must also have read permissions to the place where you store the image.

Comment: Thanks, Erik.  Doesn't this change the Web Page URL not the logo?

Comment: That setting changes the Logo URL.  For example, if you put a new image in the site assets library on the subsite, you would put the URL to you new image in the setting and the Logo would display on the Welcome page.  This setting does not change the URL of the site or any page.  If you are uncomfortable trying out the setting, then create a new subsite and change it there and when you are done, you can delete the subsite.